# InDesign GREP style ignoring last word

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm formatting a music program that mixes English and Chinese.  I read [a tip](https://forums.adobe.com/message/1318443#1318443) that suggested using the Chinese font in the style definition and then using a “GREP style” for switching to an English font (and rules) over characters in the range of those characters.

Great idea!

Note that I already am adept with regular expressions in Perl 5, and I'm also knowledgeable about Unicode including how it's organized.

Everything I find via Google on InDesign GREP Style is a basic tutorial about regular expression and dead simple to anyone who already knows Perl etc.  I've not seen anything about how InDesign 11.1.0.122 on Windows is *using* the regexp, which I assume is some *particular way*…

[image]

Note that the expression stops at the last space in the paragraph, and is not applied to the last word.  A work-around is to add extra space at the end, but that's wrong for centered text.

The expression `/[$a-$b]+/` when `$a` and `$b` include all ASCII characters will not stop *at* a space, and even if it did (e.g. some other kind of whitespace character), the stuff after it would be consecutive letters in that range, too.

So what exactly is InDesign doing with the expression, and more to the point why does it not work as stated?

(Once I get it working at all, I can improve upon it if InDesign knows the codes for Unicode properties, rather than stating a range of absolute code point values.)

Comment: Indesign has several custom matchpoints. Make nongreedy matching use **?+**. Then matching **\Z|\>** instead of space. You would get this problem even in perl

Comment: How in the world did “Laundry Song” become “Tibetan Dance” (or vice versa)?!?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Like my nephew remarked to someone selling "Texas Toast": "In Dallas we just call it Toast".  I think the English name is not a translation but the name given to it by outsiders.

Comment: @joojaa  ah... an unseen space at the end of the expression, after the '+'!  Your comment inspired me to figure that out, but I don't see how what I *reported* would be a problem or need lazy matching.

Comment: Hey i was still sleeping at 3am, hence comment not answer. glad it helped.

Comment: Well thanks for taking the moment. It was enough to get me un-stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had an unseen trailing space in the field.  Maybe you can tell in the blue highlight in the illustration once you know to look for it.  I had

```
[\x{0020}-\x{2fff}]+
```

rather than

```
[\x{0020}-\x{2fff}]+
```

due to extra space being present from the copy/paste of the string.

Don't see any difference above?  Highlight it to show where the string actually ends. ☺

Comment: Now that you mention it, I can also see that space in my post (the original tip) as well. God I hate Adobe's Jive editor  - to think I even wrote out the required space as `\x{0020}` just to make sure it would appear correctly!

Comment: The space inside the range is correct, and using \x20 emphasizes that the number is in range and contiguous.  The mistake is a space *after* the + on the end.

Comment: That's the one I meant - and it appears courtesy of the Jive editor. The only one that ought to be in the expression is the one I wrote out in full.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you said now.  The post I copied it from also had a `>` in front.